# Google Speech Quota exceeded

Tags: google-speech-api

I often receive following error when I call Google Speech API.
This error has occurred from yesterday.
*ERROR: { [Error: Quota exceeded.]
  code: 8,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient' }*

My access count is very few. It does not reach the limit(Requests per 100 seconds   = 500).

There is no error when I call the API from windows PC using same google cloud account.

How can I resolve this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: `when I call Google Speech API` can you post your code?

Comment: Hi, I referred this sample code and I use syncRecognize method.  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/recognize.js    Thank you very much.

Comment: Now it's getting better. About 50% successed.
I accessed the API from Tokyo region.I tried to connect same API from US region. It's better than accessing from Tokyo.